# Protractor Firefox 59 - Failed: TypeError: cyclic object value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, firefox, protractor

We have multiple Protractor tests for our Angular JS app.
We wanted to upgrade the Firefox version to 59 using Selenium 3.11.0.

Having upgraded anytime in the tests where we use `element(by.` to get a DOM element and then attempt to run a function on that element (like `.click()`) we get the following error

```
Failed: TypeError: cyclic object value
Build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3', time: '2018-03-11T20:33:15.31Z'
System info: host: '3930699ecd58', ip: '172.17.0.9', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.9.87-linuxkit-aufs', java.version: '1.8.0_162'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

We are going to use Firefox 58 for now but does anybody know if there is fix for this error?

Comment: You usually get that error message when using `JSON.stringify` on cyclic object values, so you should check your code base for that.

Comment: Yeah I think in the Selenium code it is running JSON.stringify on the Protractor element object. I have raised a github issue with Protractor.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this issue:

- https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/4796

Should be fixed in Firefox 62 finally.